# Store div status on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, session-state, page-refresh

I have multiple divs in one html page under common wrapper class.
I am using hide and show method on clicking next and previous option.

**What I am trying to achieve**: On page reload/refresh, the div which is showing currently should show after page reload.

So in short if you reload/refresh from pink screen, it should show same pink screen after page reload.

**What I tried:** I am storing the display properties (none or block) is local storage and on page reload trying to give same properties to divs again. Most of the responses and solution I checked in Stack overflow is regarding opening the same tab when refresh. but my case is what in same tab I have multiple div and I want to open from the same state which it was earlier.

Logic I used:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  var disp = localStorage.getItem("disp");
  var ustatus = JSON.parse(disp);
  $(".chk").text(ustatus);
  for (var x=ustatus; x<ustatus.length; x++){
    $(".pg"+x).css("display", ustatus[x]);
  }
});
```

This is fiddle link I tried:

[Page reload demo JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/972p6ysu/13/)

Comment: add your html code here

Comment: So there is like only one div that can be active simultaneously, right?

Comment: @BhumiShah - JS fiddle is there in my question with complete code details.

Comment: @seethrough - Yes, only one div to be active one time. Actually I have forms in three divs. Only after user complete one form, he can go to next form. So at one time only one page will be active. If he refresh or may be internet got disconnected, he should start from the same page. That's my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the `on` class:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  var disp = localStorage.getItem("disp");
  var ustatus = JSON.parse(disp);
  $(".chk").text(ustatus);
  for (var x=0; x<ustatus.length; x++){
    $(".pg"+(x+1)).toggleClass("off", ustatus[x]);
  }
});

$(".next").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("off");
  $(this).parent().next().removeClass("off");
});

$(".prev").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("off");
  $(this).parent().prev().removeClass("off");
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  var display = $(".clr").map(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass("off");
  }).get();
  localStorage.setItem("disp", JSON.stringify(display));
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jea6qc3/2/)

note: you can't use `$(window).on('load', ...)` in a fiddle - the JS in the editor is run on load

**EDIT:** you might also want to validate `ustatus` before applying it, something like

```
if (Array.isArray(ustatus) && ustatus.filter(x => x === true).length === 1) {
  for (var x=0; x<ustatus.length; x++){
    $(".pg"+(x+1)).toggleClass("off", ustatus[x]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML and CSS code is perfect but you need to make corrections in your JavaScript code.

**Observation 1 :** You "for" loop to assign display style has problem with variable x. You need to assign integer value to x.

**Observation 2 :** You need to remove that "display" style from "div" elements when you click on "next" and "previous" links.

Hear is new [Js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hardiksheth1717/x9mpv47e/) with updated code.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        //localStorage.removeItem("disp");
        var disp = localStorage.getItem("disp");
        var ustatus = JSON.parse(disp);
        $(".chk").text(ustatus);
        for (var x = 1; x <= ustatus.length; x++) {
            $(".pg" + x).css("display", ustatus[x-1]);
        }
    });

    $(".next").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("off").removeClass("on").removeAttr("style");
        $(this).parent().next().addClass("on").removeClass("off").removeAttr("style");
    });

    $(".prev").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("off").removeClass("on").removeAttr("style");
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("on").removeClass("off").removeAttr("style");
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        var display = $(".clr").map(function () {
            return $(this).css("display");
        }).get();
        localStorage.setItem("disp", JSON.stringify(display));
    });
```

You can also [download this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VB0AZGzGGpVMHvJN8K1N8L-La1Bnf6g/view?usp=sharing). Please run index.html to see the output.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I tried your suggestion. But, unfortunately its not working. If you click "next" and reach the cyan div, from there if you refresh the page, it should open cyan div only. rather its opening green div as of now.

Comment: Please download https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VB0AZGzGGpVMHvJN8K1N8L-La1Bnf6g/view?usp=sharing file and open index. html file

Comment: It worked dude!!  As per @ic3b3rg response, I think $(window).on('load', ...) in a fiddle was the issue that I was not able to see the changes.

Comment: Yes... You cannot run this code in fiddle... I'm glad that your problem is solved... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `display`, you can use `on` and `off` classes, i think that's why they are created for

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
var disp = localStorage.getItem("disp");
var ustatus = JSON.parse(disp);
if(ustatus!=undefined){
 $(".chk").text(ustatus);
 for (var x=1; x<=ustatus.length; x++){
   if(ustatus[x-1]=='on'){
    $(".pg"+x).addClass("on").removeClass("off");
   }
   else{
    $(".pg"+x).addClass("off").removeClass("on");
   }
 }
}

$(".next").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("off").removeClass("on");
  $(this).parent().next().addClass("on").removeClass("off");
});

$(".prev").on("click", function(){

  $(this).parent().addClass("off").removeClass("on");
  $(this).parent().prev().addClass("on").removeClass("off");
});


$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
var display = $(".clr").map(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('on'))
  return 'on';
else
  return 'off';
}).get();

localStorage.setItem("disp", JSON.stringify(display));
});
});
```

Comment: Using this approach, next and prev is not working. Please check my attempt with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/x9mpv47e/1/

Comment: while running locally, i added other events inside onload, you just have to close it }); before $(".next") and remove it from bottom.